# Creating a constant-valued matrix having the same dimensions as previously defined matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have the dimensions of a matrix **A**. I would like to create a matrix **B** (say, of only 0's) of the same size as **A**. But **A**'s dimensions are variable. Is there an efficient way using `d = Dimensions[A]`?

I could use

```
B =  Table[0, {i, d[[1]]}, {j, d[[2]]}]
```

or

```
B = A; 
B[[All, All]] = 0;
```

but I would like to generalize the algorithm to work if the order of **A** is also variable (like 3rd order tensor and so on).

In MATLAB, what I'm asking for would be `zeros(size(A))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this:

```
a = ConstantArray[1, {4, 4}]

(* ==> {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}} *)

b = ConstantArray[0, Dimensions[a]]

(* ==> {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

If your matrix has no expressions in level -1, this could work for any matrix.

```
a={{1,2,{3}},{5,6,{7,{8,9}}}}

b=Replace[a,_->0,{-1}]

(*{{0,0,{0}},{0,0,{0,{0,0}}}}*)
```

You could also do simple multiplication by `0`

```
a*0

(*{{0,0,{0}},{0,0,{0,{0,0}}}}*)
```

Comment: `a*0` must be the simplest